Path arrows in pic don't stop at node edge
This is an extension of the curved arrow path discussion from bending vs control points. It appears that using \path (c1) edge [bend left] (c2) terminates the arrow at the node center. Here's my MWE showing bending vs out/in vs control points. Am I doing something wrong or is there something unique about how path works??
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{ arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    pics/vviPic/.style args={#1}{% #1 line weight
    code = {

        \begin{scope}[nodes = draw, circle, minimum size=1.35cm, node distance=3.0cm, line width=#1,%
                            arr/.style={-{Latex[scale=1.0]}}]]
            \node at (2,2.5) (s2) {s2};
            \node[left of = s2] (s1) {s1};            

            \path[arr] (s1) edge [bend left] (s2);
             \draw[arr] (s2) to [out=200,in=340]  (s1);
            \draw[arr] (s2) .. controls ($(s2.south) + (1.0, -2.75)$) and ($(s1.south) + (-1.0, -2.75)$) .. (s1);
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic[scale=0.25] (reward) at (1,1) {vviPic=1.0pt};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The call to display the pic can be modified [scale=0.25, transform shape] to get the nodes to scale but it doesn't affect how the arrows are drawn.


Why not use \draw[arr] (s1) to [out=20,in=160] (s2); like the arrow in the other direction?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That was my solution. I drew all my arrows using out/in. The question was more fundamental in why path does what it does.

I don't think it is the \path, more the edge: \draw[arr] (s1) edge [bend left] (s2);              \path[draw,arr] (s2) to [out=200,in=340]  (s1);

you are misusing edge, imho. edge is a detour. (or, sometimes, it has more specialised uses.) if you say \path (a) edge (b); you start and end at (a). if you say \path (a) (b); you start at (a) and end at (b). so, in your example, (s2) is not the end of the path. it is a node part way along the path. and nodes on paths are anchored by their centres by default.

It's a bug: #1251.
